# How continue line of text to next line in Mercury?

Tags: mercury

How do I continue a too-long line to a next line? I tried using a backslash but the Mercury compiler doesn't accept that convention. Have been unable to find an answer to this mundane question.

Comment: Can you show us the specific case that you're having trouble with?

Whitespace is not significant in Mercury (except in string constants) so you shouldn't need to do anything special at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had used an editor to type a very long list of comma-separated integers. What I typed was something like (there was no ellipsis in what I typed)

A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 65, 97, 211, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 47, 48, 51, 53, 57, 61, 75, 8006, 227, 301, 4093, 433, 225,..., 287].

This line has naturally wrapped above, but on my editor it simply extended far to the right, and I wanted to fold the line so that it would all fit within editor lines that could be printed and easily read. The system accepted my list when I left it as a single long line, but when I tried to break it up into separate lines it gave me error messages. I didn't keep a record of what those messages were and can no longer remember. I was using a TextWrangler editor with the 'soft wrap' feature disabled. That probably would have solved my problem. The result would have looked right, and the compiler would probably have had no problem with it. I must have introduced end-of-line symbols that confused the Mercury system. I think that's the answer. Thinking through this has been helpful.